# Do you use 'a voice who' in this case?

Tags: usage

According to lots of dictionaries, ***voice*** only refers to ***a singer***, when it relates to a person. Does it also refer to ***a person who expresses an opinion*** like the one in the following sentence?

> "That has made him an independent voice but conservative voice who
> actually solves the problem". - The New York Times

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify a dictionary, but [Wiktionary has](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/voice#Noun) "One who speaks" and "An expressed opinion".

[Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/voice) has "an expression of opinion" or  the person who is able to express an important quality or opinion:

[Cambridge Learners' dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/voice) has "someone who expresses the opinions or wishes of a group of people"

Lexico has "A particular opinion or attitude expressed."

I suggest your dictionary search hasn't been thorough enough.

Comment: Oh, thank you, James K.

Comment: In the example sentence, you can't use 'voice which,' can you?

Comment: @Sungry If you have a new question, please open it as a new question. But no, it's best to use "who" for people, even if you have referenced a person by metaphorically using a word that is not normally a person.